# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow to give option of sending email or not

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I'm making a workflow in SharePoint Designer to send an email when an event is created. I made a list that gives the option to send an email or not and put an if-else statement within my workflow, but the workflow sends an email either way. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a workflow for that task list and be sure to check if "Creating a new item will start this workflow" is checked in the start options .

Comment: Right it will send an email automatically, but if you check the option "Do not send an email" the workflow will still send an email out to the recipients.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: I was not putting my if else statement in the same group by accident, so the workflow was ignoring the else statement. The working code went like this:

If *Events calendar: value* equals *send email*
    Email *recipients*
else
    *stop the workflow* and *log* [text]